# Make KMeans model from Longitude & Latitude and get clusters

Tags: python, android, arrays, numpy, cluster-computing

I'm trying to run the lines of code below but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: '(['Latitude'], ['Longitude'])' is an invalid key
```

```
# Make KMeans model from Longitude & Latitude and get clusters

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X_train_lat_long = train_df[['Latitude'], ['Longitude']].to_numpy()
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4).fit(X_train_lat_long)
kmeans.labels_
```

Comment: `X_train_lat_long = train_df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].to_numpy()`

Answer (score 0):

If the data is coming from a small area away from the 180th meridian you can use k-means. But if it comes from all over the globe you have more serious problems. The space you are using is not at all Euclidian and doesn't support taking a mean. So k-means will execute but potentially give a far from optimal answer.

You can use k-medoids instead. It will not return the mean but it will return the most central data point of each cluster.

Using k-medoids requires calculation of all distances before clustering. In this case you would have to use the great-circle distance between two locations (aka orthodromic distance or spherical distance).